# import tkinter yields error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics

Starting the Open Book on Python 3.1

```
import turtle #this yields an error from importing tkinter
```

Script:

```
import tkinter
exit()
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imptk.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python is incorrectly installed, the library in question has been compiled for the wrong architecture, maybe the wrong processor or for 32 bit when it should have been 64, or similar. In any case this is not a programming error.

Comment: Thanks.  I uninstalled 3.1, installed 3.2.1 and the ActiveTcl 8.5.10.1 and no more tkinter error.